# 1+2+4 in Binary bits

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

I have an email from a developer in which he says:

> As you may know 1110000000000000 means 1+2+4

I won't be able to contact him for a few days. Can anyone else explain how that is possible?

Numbers appear to be turned into binary using the following function:

```
function toBinaryString(bitmask)
tvar2 = 0
tvar3 = 1
tvar1 = ""
do while tvar2 < 16 
    if (bitmask and tvar3) > 0 then
        tvar1 = tvar1 & "1"
    else
        tvar1 = tvar1 & "0"
    end if
    tvar3 = tvar3 * 2
    tvar2 = tvar2 + 1
loop
toBinaryString = tvar1
end function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's little endian notation ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)). Basicaly the least significant bits appear on the left, unlike big endian notation (which is what most people think of when talking about binary).

As such the first bit represents 0^2, then 1^2, 2^2 etc. (so 1 + 2 + 4).

Comment: ok so you seem to understand this stuff. Do you mind explaining a little bit more for me please I can't find any info on counting in little endian on the link you sent or anywhere else...

Comment: It works in the same way as big endian notation does, it's just written backwards. So your first 8 bits represent the following values: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, compared to big endian which is: 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1.

Comment: 124 in big endian is 1111100. I understand that 01, 10, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000, all the way up, but how does that work in little endian? I still don't see how 1110000000000000 = 1+2+4, sorry I'm just not getting it...

Comment: It's OK. I'll see if I can explain a little better. Big endian notation you count from right to left (so the right most bit represents one, the one after that represents 2, and the one after that represents 4). In little endian, it's the other way around, the left most bit represents 1, the next bit is 2, and 4 is after that (so 01 in big endian is the same as 10 in little endian, 0100 in big endian is the same as 0010 in little endian). Sorry if you're still confused, but I'm not sure how to explain it. Try having a look at http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html

Comment: Sorry to be a prick about it, but this is not little endian notation. If this is written in little endian, then you have to split it up into 2 8-bit bytes as in: 11100000 00000000 where the first byte is the least significant, resulting in 224 in decimal notation. In a byte, the leftmost bit is always the most significant just as with numbers, where the leftmost digit is always the most significant. Only the byte order can be different. What the asker is delivered could be called "reversed byte notation" and is just as impractical as using 53356 as the reversed digit notation for 65335.

Comment: It is not little endian but it is in LSB notation (Least significant bit first)

Answer (score 2):

Prepare for some interesting reading material: [How bytes work](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/bytes.htm)

Actually your developer is not correct, 1110000000000000 in binary notation is 57344 in decimal notation.